# MediaCodec createInputSurface() throws illegal state exception

Tags: android

In my Android app, I need to encode live camera video in gpu. Here is some relevant code:

```
    MediaFormat format = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat(MIME_TYPE, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT,
            MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatSurface);
    format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, BITRATE);
    format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, FRAME_RATE);
    format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, IFRAME_INTERVAL);

    this._encoder = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType(MIME_TYPE);
    this._encoder.configure(format, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);
    Surface s = this._encoder.createInputSurface();
```

When `MIME_TYPE` is `MediaFormat.MIMETYPE_VIDEO_AVC,`, this code works as expected. However, when the mime type is `MediaFormat.MIMETYPE_VIDEO_VP8,` the call to `createInputSurface()` throws an illegal state exception. Here is some more info from logcat:

```
I/ACodec: setupVideoEncoder succeeded
E/OMXNodeInstance: OMX_GetExtensionIndex OMX.google.android.index.storeMetaDataInBuffers failed
E/ACodec: [OMX.google.vpx.encoder] onCreateInputSurface returning error -2147483648
W/MediaCodec: createInputSurface failed, err=-2147483648
```

I am thinking vp8 encoder is present on the device. Otherwise, `MediaCodec.configure()` would have failed. Appreciate your insight on why `createInputSurface()` fails? Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My tests were on a device running OS 4.3. It seems this problem was fixed in version 4.4 and up as per this discussion: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58834